# creating uppertriangularized matrix

Tags: matrix

I am trying to create an uppertriangularized matrix of arbitrary size,*max* of the form

```
{{1,2,3,4,5},{0,1,2,3,4},{0,0,1,2,3},{0,0,0,1,2},{0,0,0,0,1}}
```

using the code

```
table = Table[mu^(j - 1) Exp[-mu]/(j - 1)!, {i, 1, lambda}, {j, i, lambda}];
me = UpperTriangularize[table];
ve = dNdt[[1 ;; lambda]];
dadt = LinearSolve[me, ve];
```

where max is 5 here, but can be varied arbitrarily. Would appreciate advice.

Comment: max is meant to be lambda in the code.

Comment: Then what's `dNdt`? Why do you say `max` is a 5*5 matrix? The question is quite unclear at the moment, please edit the question to clarify.

Comment: I used a 5x5 matrix as example, In reality, it will be a lambda by lambda uppertriangularized matrix as the sample code indicated. Also dNdt is a vector of length equal to lambda.

Comment: Do you require `PadLeft[Reverse@Range@Range[5]]`?

Comment: I tried  above set of four lines of code and got an unsatisfactory answer. The first line was not in a list format and when applied UpperTriangularize to me, it did not show zeroing of the lower triangular matrix.